# Javascript remote src not working

Tags: javascript

If I put JavaScript inline in my page it works fine; however, if I put the script on a remote server so I can clean things up, it quits working.

Go to:
http://www.salescart.com/cloud/store/test2.html

Here is the JavaScript is **inline**
{you can see the iframe sizes correctly without issue at this url}

Go to:
http://www.salescart.com/cloud/store/test.html

This is the same exact html file except that the operative javascript is put into a remote src.
This is the JavaScript in the remote **src**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //MDN PolyFil for IE8 (This is not needed if you use the jQuery version)
  if (!Array.prototype.forEach){
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisArg */){
      "use strict";
      if (this === void 0 || this === null || typeof fun !== "function")
        throw new TypeError();

      var t = Object(this),
          len = t.length >>> 0,
          thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (i in t)
          fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
    };
  }
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.salescart.net/checkout20/src/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  iFrameResize({
    log                 : true,          // Enable console logging
    enablePublicMethods : true,          // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
    checkOrigin       : false          // Disable CheckOrigin
  });
</script>
```

{you can see the iframe stops resizing}

I don't understand exactly why this is the case.  I appreciate in advance your help.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't have HTML in JavaScript files.

Comment: in the js file you don't need the `<script></script>`. As for the other libraries loaded in your js file, add those files in the HTML of the page, not in the javascript file.

Comment: Ok, what html do I have in the file?  Do you mean the "<script type="text/javascript">" ?

Comment: Ok, I removed the <script> tags and its still not working.  So I can't load the libraries "remotely"?

Comment: Yes, Michael, they meant exactly that. Thous tags you should put in html file to include there the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the js file you wrote

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js";
src="http://www.salescart.net/checkout20/src/iframeResizer.min.js";
```

which wont work. You need to load those js files in the tests.html itself. Preferablly in the the head tag as

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.salescart.net/checkout20/src/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to load those in the remote file as well?  I'm trying to reduce the typed code footprint on the html side of things.  Thanks.

Comment: there are ways but those are loaded asynchronously and u will have to write call backs which makes ur code very complicated.

Comment: Ok...thanks.  I'm trying for KISS so that definitely sounds like the wrong direction.